# Set table cell value based on index using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this approach (https://dotnetfiddle.net/UjxtUW) to create a dynamic table in a MVC view.

The cells in the table has textbox and some text boxes values are populated via jQuery UI dialog. The code to open corresponding dialog box is,

```
$("#invItemsTable").on('click', 'td', function () {
   var cIndex = $(this).index();
   var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   rowIndex = $tr.index();
   if (cIndex == 7)
       $("#dlAccCode").dialog("open");
   else if (cIndex == 0)
       $("#mdGrnList").dialog("open");
   else if (cIndex == 5)
       $("#dlTaxCode").dialog("open");
});
```

When the user selects a record in the dialog box, the CODE of that particular record is set to the table cell value by,

```
$("#AccCodeTable").delegate("input[type='radio']", "change", function (){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#invItemsTable [id$=txtAccCode]').slice(rowIndex).val($this.val());
    $('#dlAccCode').dialog("close");
 });
```

The problem is if there are 5 rows in the table and if I change the 'CODE' of 3rd record, then 4th and 5th also updated with the same value.

This below code is also not working.

```
$('#invItemsTable tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ') td:eq(5)').val($this.val());
```

Please advice, if there is any way to set the text box value using column index and row index of the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `slice` statement. [Slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) takes 2 parameters, `start` and `end` which define the first and last indexes of items you wish to select from the array. If `end` is omitted, slice will return all array elements from `start` index to the end of the array. You need to define `end` if you only want one element.

Change:

`$('#invItemsTable [id$=txtAccCode]').slice(rowIndex).val($this.val());`

To:

`$('#invItemsTable [id$=txtAccCode]').slice(rowIndex, rowIndex + 1).val($this.val());`

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('td').click(function () {
            $('#txt').val($(this).text())
        });


        $('#btnset').click(function () {

            var rowIndex = 1;
            $('#invItemsTable tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ')').find('td:eq(5)').text($('#txt').val());
        });

    });



</script>



<body>
    <input type="button" id="btnset" value="SetContent"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt"/>
    <table style="width:50%" id="invItemsTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>66</td>
  </tr>
</table> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Saravanan Sachi plz check this

Answer (score 0):

use nth-child :

```
$('#invItemsTable tr:nth-child(' + rowIndex + ') td:nth-child(5)').val($this.val());
```

Comment: This is a bit of a kludge. It might work, but his code was close and cleaner, he was just missing a bit. This introduces dependencies on his HTML structure.

Comment: This is just about his 3rd code example. I suggested `nth-child` because `eq` is 0-based index , while `nth-child` starts with 1 . Maybe you're right, his just missing something.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that part. My mistake! :)